# Flask Form submit issues

Tags: flask

I have a form on my index.html and I have a app.py to process it but it does nothing. The data isnt processed and the redirect doesnt happen. Pressing the submit button does nothing so it seems as if the app.py isnt working but I have app.py running and Im using http://127.0.0.1:5000/. In my terminal app.py is running without any errors.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        phone = request.form['phone']
        message = request.form['message']
        print(name, email, phone, message)
        return render_template('success.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b015121141.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 768px)" href="../static/css/mobile.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1100px)" href="../static/css/widescreen.css">
  <title>System Services</title>

</head>

<body id="home">

  <!-- Section: Contact-->
  <section id="contact">
    <div class="contact-form bg-primary p-2">
      <h2 class="m-heading">Contact Us</h2>
      <p>Please Use the form below to contact us</p>
      <form action="/submit" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="phone">Phone</label>
          <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message">Message</label>
          <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-dark">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="map"></div>
  </section>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer id="main-footer" class="bg-dark text-center py-1">
    <div class="container">
      <p>Copyright &copy; 2019, All Rights Reserved</p>
    </div>
  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and works fine. I checked your POST values in your view and they are all there. The only error i got was that `success.html` does not exist which actually was not there. Create the `success.html` file in yor templates folder and you should be fine.

Comment: the success file is there as well. I didnt include it on here because its basically nothing. But it does exist so why doesnt this code work for me?

Answer (score 0):

Your code just work fine insofar as you add sucess.html

If you have any more issues, I invite you to check one of my project (well documented) which uses django POST method and generate something (in my case a .docx file with user datas) : [Flask Docx Generator](https://github.com/emiledelmas/Website_Docx_Generator)

If this project was helful you can upvote my answer and put it as the answer of your problem :)

Comment: success.html has been there since i wrote this, I didnt include it on here. The code still doesnt work. THe browser just sits there and no results are returned by the app.py